# C++ strptime not filling in year

Tags: c++, strptime

I'm trying to parse a string into a struct tm using strptime.  Looks easy enough, but it is not filling in the year correctly (yes, I know about the 1900 offset) - after the call, the year is set to 0.  Other fields look ok.  See below:

```
struct tm tm;
memset(&tm, 0, sizeof(struct tm));
strptime("Fri Jan 17 09:44:33 UTC 2014", "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y", &tm);
```

After the strptime call, the tm struct is as follows - note that tm_year=0, where I am expecting it to be 114:

```
{tm_sec = 33, tm_min = 44, tm_hour = 9, tm_mday = 17, tm_mon = 0, tm_year = 0,
 tm_wday = 5, tm_yday = 0, tm_isdst = 0, tm_gmtoff = 0, tm_zone = 0x0}
```

I'm sure I'm missing something simple - can anyone point it out to me?

Comment: I would guess that it tries to match the whole string in %Z

Comment: It works in Python, though not in C++: `>>> datetime.datetime.strptime("Fri Jan 17 09:44:33 UTC 2014", "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y")
datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 17, 9, 44, 33)`

Comment: Yep, that's it.  If I remove the %Z and use the following format string, I get the year correctly: "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S UTC %Y".  Since I know all times will be in UTC, I can get away with this, though not graceful.  I might try a sscanf approach...

Comment: I always thought that this date-time format was incredibly stupid.

Comment: Goodness, who ever settled on such an horrid format ?

Comment: Unfortunately it's a piece of 3rd party hardware, so my hands are tied...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my system (Mac OS X), `man strptime` has this note about %Z:

> The %Z format specifier only accepts time zone abbreviations of the
>   local time zone, or the value
>        "GMT".  This limitation is because of ambiguity due to of the over loading of time zone abbreviations.
>        One such example is EST which is both Eastern Standard Time and Eastern Australia Summer Time.

And indeed, if I change your "UTC" to "GMT", the code suddenly works.  Note that Python for whatever reason is smarter here, and supports "UTC" as well.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies.  As I commented above, I can work around this now that I know the issue!